# How to do regression if one is not sure of dependent variable?

Tags: regression, causality

I have data on age, gender, height and weight of subjects, and also levels of 2 chemicals in blood of these subjects (chem1 and chem2). It is not clear whether chem1 affects chem2 or chem2 affects chem1. How should I procedd with analysis if I am not clear which of these 2 (chem1 and chem2) is the dependent variable? Age, gender, height and weight may modify the affect of one chemical on the other.

Comment: A third (and perhaps more productive) possibility is to model them both simultaneously -- multivariate multiple regression

Comment: What I understand from your suggestion is that I assume both as dependent variables while age, gender etc are independent variables. But that is not correct. In the body one chemical is affecting the other while age, gender etc may only be modifying this response. Is it possible to determine statistically the sequence of events that may be happening?

Comment: Cross-sectional models can sometimes identify association, but won't put heads on arrows.

Answer (score 2):

With cross-sectional data, and no instrument (as in an instrumental variables approach) you won't be able to identify which chemical "causes" which. You are better off reframing your question and considering relationships, rather than causality. Consider a structural equation model approach, in which case you would model both as outcome variables and have a correlation between the two.

$chem_1=age+gender+height+weight$

$chem_2=age+gender+height+weight$

$cov(chem_1,chem_1)$

I can't draw a path diagram here, but that may help you see things visually. This will give you the relationship of each independent variable with each chemical, allow you to test whether those relationships are different across chemicals, and quantify the relationship between the two chemicals, conditioned on your independent variables.